# Different behavior of progress bars: local vs. remote ssh bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, wget, subshell

I am having issues to get minimal progress bars working in local scripts which are executed remotely via ssh. Depending on the command I get other undesired progress indicators (lines of dots with wget) or just noting (with pv | tar)

Let me give you an example of what I mean:

```
wget -q --show-progress https://some.file -P /tmp
some.file     11%[=========>          ]  20,08M  4,47MB/s    ETA 38s  # Nice looking progress bar
```

The same line of code executed remotely:

```
ssh user@server 'wget -q --show-progress https://some.file -P /tmp'
     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1,43M 2m6s  # Not so nice for longer scripts and big files
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1,73M 1m55s 
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 5,16M 88s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 2,56M 84s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 5,14M 74s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 5,36M 67s
... (etc)
```

I should mention that curl just works fine. But as I said, I have the same problem with pv when trying to get any kind of progress bar while extracting with tar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page:

> `--progress=type`
>       Select the type of the progress indicator you wish to use.  Legal indicators are "dot" and "bar".
>
> The "bar" indicator is used by default.  It draws an ASCII progress bar graphics (a.k.a "thermometer" display) indicating the
>   status of retrieval.  **If the output is not a TTY, the "dot" bar will be used by default.**

The progress bar in your first snippet is "bar", and the second is "dot". When you run `ssh` with a command given on the command line, it doesn't allocate a tty on the remote side by default, so that's probably what triggers `wget` to change the progress bar style.

You could use `wget --progress=bar:force` to force it to se that style; or use `ssh -t` to tell the SSH client to allocate a TTY.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This absolutely solved the issue for wget as I can force the bar style. It also works with `ssh -t` but I am trying to avoid this option as it might cause other issues (programs really expecting a user to be there in order to interact if necessary).

With you explanation and the manpage I figured out that the corresponding flag for `pv` is `-f`